# Objective-C で iPhone 端末の種別を判別するには？

Tags: ios, xcode, objective-c, iphone, xcode6

デバイス別に処理を分けるには条件はどう書けば良いのでしょうか？？

できれば iPhone 6 Plus, iPhone 6, iPhone 5s, iPhone 5 の判定条件を教えて下さい。
Objective-Cでよろしくお願いします。

Comment: [このアプローチ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11197770/1167750)はどうでしょうか？

Comment: Hiroshi Yamamotoさん詳しく答えて頂きありがとうございます。
無事、問題は解決できました。

Comment: summeaさんも回答ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### モデル番号から判別する

[英語版の記事](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11197509/ios-iphone-get-device-model-and-make)に詳しくありますが、モデル番号を uname で取得して判断するのが手っ取り早いです。
今回は iPhone 5, 6, Plusの判別がされたいとのことなのでそのサンプルコードを示します。

```
#import <sys/utsname.h>
...    
...

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    NSString* deviceName = getDeviceName();

    bool is_Simulator =  ([deviceName isEqualToString:@"i386"] || [deviceName isEqualToString:@"x86_64"]);
    bool is_iPhone5 = ([deviceName hasPrefix:@"iPhone5,"] || [deviceName hasPrefix:@"iPhone6,"]);
    bool is_iPhone6 =  ([deviceName isEqualToString:@"iPhone7,2"]);
    bool is_iPhone6Plus =  ([deviceName isEqualToString:@"iPhone7,1"]);

    NSLog(@"Device Name: %@",deviceName);
    NSLog(@"Is Simulator? => %@", is_Simulator ? @"YES":@"NO");
    NSLog(@"Is iPhone5? => %@", is_iPhone5 ? @"YES":@"NO");
    NSLog(@"Is iPhone6? => %@", is_iPhone6 ? @"YES":@"NO");
    NSLog(@"Is iPhone6Plus? => %@", is_iPhone6Plus ? @"YES":@"NO");

}

// モデル名を取得する
NSString* getDeviceName()
{
    struct utsname systemInfo;
    uname(&systemInfo);

    return [NSString stringWithCString:systemInfo.machine
                              encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}
```

実行結果

```
DeviceTest[####:##x] hardware: iPhone7,2
DeviceTest[####:##x] Is Simulator? => NO
DeviceTest[####:##x] Is iPhone5? => NO
DeviceTest[####:##x] Is iPhone6? => YES
DeviceTest[####:##x] Is iPhone6Plus? => NO
```

### UIDevice ライブラリを使用する

[iOS7 Cookbook のレポジトリ](https://github.com/erica/iOS-7-Cookbook/tree/master/C14%20Device/02%20-%20UIDevice-Hardware)に、小さなライブラリと良いサンプルがあります。

ただ、このライブラリだと iPhone6 はラベルが Unknown デバイスとして
認識されるので注意してください。モデル番号で判別するならば問題ないですが、
ラベルが必要な場合は、自分で少し更新する必要があります。

```
UIDevice *device = [UIDevice currentDevice];
NSLog(@"Platform: %@", device.platform);
NSLog(@"HWModel: %@", device.hwmodel);
NSLog(@"Platform type: %d", device.platformType);
NSLog(@"Platform string: %@", device.platformString);
NSLog(@"Bus Freq: %d", device.busFrequency);
NSLog(@"CPU Count: %d", device.cpuCount);
NSLog(@"Total memory: %ud", device.totalMemory);
NSLog(@"Mac address: %@", device.macaddress);
NSLog(@"Retina display: %d", device.hasRetinaDisplay);
```

### モデル番号のリスト

Wikipedia 項目 "[List of iOS devices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_iOS_devices)" の、"Hardware Strings"の行を参考にしてください。

```
i386      , iPhone Simulator  
iPhone1,1 , iPhone  
iPhone1,2 , iPhone 3G  
iPhone2,1 , iPhone 3GS  
iPhone3,1 , iPhone 4  
iPhone3,2 , iPhone 4 GSM Rev A  
iPhone3,3 , iPhone 4 CDMA  
iPhone4,1 , iPhone 4S  
iPhone5,1 , iPhone 5 (GSM)  
iPhone5,2 , iPhone 5 (GSM+CDMA)  
iPhone5,3 , iPhone 5C (GSM)  
iPhone5,4 , iPhone 5C (Global)  
iPhone6,1 , iPhone 5S (GSM)  
iPhone6,2 , iPhone 5S (Global)  
iPhone7,1 , iPhone 6 Plus  
iPhone7,2 , iPhone 6  
iPod1,1   , 1st Gen iPod  
iPod2,1   , 2nd Gen iPod  
iPod3,1   , 3rd Gen iPod  
iPod4,1   , 4th Gen iPod  
iPod5,1   , 5th Gen iPod  
iPad1,1   , iPad  
iPad1,2   , iPad 3G  
iPad2,1   , 2nd Gen iPad  
iPad2,2   , 2nd Gen iPad GSM  
iPad2,3   , 2nd Gen iPad CDMA  
iPad2,4   , 2nd Gen iPad New Revision  
iPad3,1   , 3rd Gen iPad  
iPad3,2   , 3rd Gen iPad CDMA  
iPad3,3   , 3rd Gen iPad GSM  
iPhone5,1 , iPhone 5 GSM+LTE  
iPhone5,2 , iPhone 5 CDMA+LTE  
iPod5,1   , 5th Gen iPod  
iPad2,5   , iPad mini  
iPad2,6   , iPad mini GSM+LTE  
iPad2,7   , iPad mini CDMA+LTE  
iPad3,4   , 4th Gen iPad  
iPad3,5   , 4th Gen iPad GSM+LTE  
iPad3,6   , 4th Gen iPad CDMA+LTE  
iPad4,1   , iPad Air (WiFi)  
iPad4,2   , iPad Air (GSM+CDMA)  
iPad4,4   , iPad mini Retina (WiFi)  
iPad4,5   , iPad mini Retina (GSM+CDMA)  
iPad4,6   , iPad mini Retina (China)  
iPad5,3   , iPad Air 2 (WiFi)  
iPad5,4   , iPad Air 2 (GSM+CDMA)  
iPad4,7   , iPad mini 3 (WiFi)  
iPad4,8   , iPad mini 3 (GSM+CDMA)
```